# Вроде все правильно,а на Stepik выдает ошибку.В чем проблема?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача:

> Напишите программу, на вход которой подаётся список чисел одной
> строкой. Программа должна для каждого элемента этого списка вывести
> сумму двух его соседей. Для элементов списка, являющихся крайними,
> одним из соседей считается элемент, находящий на противоположном конце
> этого списка. Например, если на вход подаётся список "1 3 5 6 10", то
> на выход ожидается список "13 6 9 15 7" (без кавычек).

Если на вход пришло только одно число, надо вывести его же.

Вывод должен содержать одну строку с числами нового списка, разделёнными пробелом.

```
Sample Input 1:
1 3 5 6 10
Sample Output 1:
13 6 9 15 7
Sample Input 2:
10
Sample Output 2:
10
```

Мое решение:

```
num = str(input()).split(" ")
numlen = len(num)
for i in num:
 if numlen == 1:
      print(i)
      break
 elif  i == num[0]:
       a = int(num[-1]) + int(num[1])
 elif i == num[1]:
      b = int(num[2]) + int(num[0])
 elif i == num[2]:
      c = int(num[3]) + int(num[1])
 elif i == num[3]:
      d = int(num[4]) + int(num[2])
 elif i == num[4]:
      w = int(num[0]) + int(num[3])
      print(a,b,c,d,w)
```

Интерпретатор Python 3.7 выдает все верно. Сайт же не принимает решение и выдает вот такую вот ошибку:

> b = int(num[2]) + int(num[0])
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что адресовать его надо преподавателю курса.

Comment: Это ошибка говорит, что вы входите за рамки массива. А какое значение

Comment: Покажите входные данные свои.

Comment: Sample Input 1:
1 3 5 6 10
Sample Output 1:
13 6 9 15 7
Sample Input 2:
10
Sample Output 2:
10

Comment: В условии ничего не сказано про количество чисел в списке. Попробуйте подать на вход, например, `1 2`.

Comment: @Zlata_666 есть сомнения, что Вы именно такие данные на вход подаёте.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 ,и вы правы.

Comment: @Zlata_666, условие вопроса должно быть в самом вопросе, а не по ссылке. Поэтому, пожалуйста, сделайте правку вопроса и добавьте текст задачи. UPD. спасибо за оперативность :)

Comment: @gil9red спасибо большое за замечание.
Правка внесена .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код не работает при 2 элементах.

Вот работающий код:

```py
li = input().split()      # split() то же самое, что и split(' ')

len_li = len(li)
if len_li == 1:           # Если 1 элемент, просто печатаем его и завершаем программу
    print(li[0])
    exit()

res = []                  # В этот список будем добавлять вычисленные значения
for i in range(len_li):
    if i == len_li - 1:   # см. сноска №2
        b = int(li[0])
    else:
        b = int(li[i+1])
    a = int(li[i-1])      # см. сноска №1

    res.append(a + b)     # Добавляем в наш массив очередной результат

print(*res)               # см сноска №3
```

**UPD:**

*Сноска №1:*
В Python можно обращаться к элементу списка по отрицательному индексу, таким образом `li[-1]` то же самое, что `li[len(li) - 1]`. Мы так можем получить соседний с первым элемент (последний).

*Сноска №2:*
Нельзя выходить за пределы. Когда мы дойдём до `li[len(li) - 1]` элемента, строка `b = int(li[i+1])` выведет нас за пределы массива, будет ошибка. Мы должны её исключить.

*Сноска №3:*
Почти аналогично:

```py
for x in res:
    print(x, end=' ')
```

Вот только код выше напечатает лишний пробел в конце.

Comment: Очень благодарна вам за это решение,я его проверила-все работает.
Чувствую себя самым глупым новичком на свете.Каким то маленьким котенком.
Вы бы не могли объяснить логику вашего кода,что я все поняла и в следующий раз у меня не возникало проблем.
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: @Zlata_666 Пояснил, надеюсь, что помог Вам.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 2):

Аналогично предыщему ответу, но работает с индексами через деление по модулю:

```
items = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
size = len(items)
if size == 1:
    print(items[0])
else:
    new_items = []
    for i in range(size):
        li = (i - 1) % size
        ri = (i + 1) % size
        new_items.append(items[li] + items[ri])

    print(*new_items)
```